# Problem with setValue() function in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, error-999999

I'm trying to add data to an attribute table in ArcGIS 10 using the following code:

```
def make_floor_no( shapefile ):
    "Makes header for number of Floors (FLO) and calculates value"

    fieldName = "FLO"
    try:
        ARCPY.AddField_management(shapefile, fieldName, "DOUBLE")
    except:
        print "Field already there"  

    # loop through attribute table    
    Rows = ARCPY.SearchCursor( shapefile ) 

    for row in Rows:
        floors = round( row.getValue( 'HGT' ) / 3.0, 0)
        print str(floors)
        row.setValue( fieldName, floors )
        Rows.updateRow(row)
```

However, I keep getting an error along the line

```
row.setValue( fieldName, floors )
```

I can't spot anything wrong with this, and have tried a few different options. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

The error message is as follows:

```
 File "Z:\ConstructionMaterial.py", line 100, in <module> make_floor_no( InputFile )
 File "Z:\ConstructionMaterial.py", line 71, in make_floor_no 
    row.setValue( fieldName, floors )
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\arcobjects.py", line 941, in setValue
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.SetValue(*gp_fixargs(args)))
RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Search cursors get you read-only rows objects.  if you want to update you need to use the update cursor.

So change this

```
    Rows = ARCPY.SearchCursor( shapefile )
```

To this

```
    Rows = ARCPY.UpdateCursor( shapefile )
```